# createInstantRoom throwing error in strophe.muc.js

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe, multiuserchat, strophe.js

I'm trying to create muc room using createInstantRoom method in strophe.muc.js, but its throwing error. can anyone plese tell me what is the format of room name given as input to createInstantRoom method

I tried this:
this.globalConnection.muc.createInstantRoom('testGroup@conference.localhost/879FKQVK0NZVMWRYQ8@localhost', this.onSuccess, this.onFailure);

This is the error call backfunction response:

…

Comment: Can you add the full error response to the question? This "..." doesn't look complete. (You can print the entire XML data to the console by assigning console.log to both `rawInput` and `rawOutput` properties of the connection object.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about strophe, but this sounds wrong:

> testGroup@conference.localhost/879FKQVK0NZVMWRYQ8@localhost

If that argument is the room JID, then it's probably better something like:

> testGroup@conference.localhost